# blur function if it is not clicked in other input button

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('input[type="text"]').css({'width': '0px', 'border-width': '0px'});
var noOfClicks = 0;
$('input[type="text"]').on('blur',function(e){
    if(e.target !== $(this).next()){
        $(this).animate({'width': '0px', 'border-width': '0px'});
        noOfClicks = 0;
    }
});
$('input[type="image"]').on('click',function(e){


    if(++noOfClicks % 2 !== 0)
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev().animate({'width': '338px', 'border-width': '1px'});
})
```

I want to animate the text box if it is blurred but not if user clicked to the `input[type="image"]` button.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kynxd2yb/1/)

I am pretty sure that I'm doing wrong here in line:

```
if(e.target !== $(this).next()){
```

Comment: `(e.target !== $(this).next())`?

Comment: Do you know the meaning of "blur" ? , When control loses the focus it will fire the blur event .

Comment: try this updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/cnv29sex/)

Comment: @Rajesh You may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place both elements in a container div, then remove the blur event of the text box. Then hide the textbox, whenever user clicks outside of that div

```
$('input[type="image"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev().animate({
        'width': '338px',
        'border-width': '1px'
    });
})
$(document).click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var container = $('div');

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('input[type="text"]').animate({
            'width': '0px',
            'border-width': '0px'
        });
    }

});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kynxd2yb/3/)

Comment: Oh! in my local project I did something wrong. It's working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since the blur event happens right after something loses focus and before the next element is focused, I suggest you either:

- set a small timer that will check if the focused element is that image input, and if it is not, it would run the callback
- or listen to the body focus event instead of the text input blur event, that way you'll have enough time to check what's being focused and decide what to do

Comment: is there another good way to have the effect like I want? If so, please show me a demo. Thanks.

Comment: There surely is, I gave you the two I thought were the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Its working as expected. All you need to do is make sure you have the input in focus whenever you click on search. So now whenever you click outside the input, your blur event will be triggered.

```
$('input[type="text"]').css({'width': '0px', 'border-width': '0px'});
var noOfClicks = 0;
$('input[type="text"]').on('blur',function(e){
    if(e.target !== $(this).next()){
        $(this).animate({'width': '0px', 'border-width': '0px'});
        noOfClicks = 0;
    }
});
$('input[type="image"]').on('click',function(e){


    if(++noOfClicks % 2 !== 0)
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev().animate({'width': '338px', 'border-width': '1px'}).focus();

})
```

Link to fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kynxd2yb/2/

Comment: It's not working. Type something and click search. This should not animate then.